# Laravel 5 select columns that are unique

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

It'm trying to use the Laravel 5 query builder and select unique rows from a MySQL table using the following code, but it doesn't seem to select unique rows.

Any idea what could be wrong?

```
BookingDates::distinct('parking_bay')->where('date', $date)->take(3)->get()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to specify a database column in your `distinct()` clause. Try this, it should return an array of column values for `parking_bay` based on your criteria:

`BookingDates::distinct()->where('date', $date)->take(3)->lists('parking_bay');`